# Bitnami Redmineにcontactsプラグインを入れると500エラーになる

Tags: redmine

RedmineもRubyも触り始めたばかりで対策がわからずに困っています。
アドバイスお願いします。

[問題]
Redmineにcontacts(CRM)プラグインを導入してメニューのコンタクトのページに行くと
500エラーが発生する。

[環境]
Win7 x64
Bitnami Redmine 3.3.3-0
[Redmine CRM plugin (Light version)](http://www.redmine.org/plugins/redmine_contacts)

[実施したこと]
プラグインをフォルダにコピー後に下記コマンドを実行

```
bundle install --without development test RAILS_ENV=production
bundle exec rake redmine:plugins NAME=redmine_contacts RAILS_ENV=production
rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV="production"
```

サーバー再起動

[エラーログ]

> Started GET "/redmine/contacts" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-05-17 06:40:35 +0900
>   Processing by ContactsController#index as HTML
>     Current user: admin (id=1)
>     Rendered plugins/redmine_contacts/app/views/contacts/_upgrade_to_pro.html.erb (0.0ms)
>     Rendered plugins/redmine_contacts/app/views/common/_sidebar.html.erb (0.0ms)
>     Rendered plugins/redmine_contacts/app/views/contacts/_tags_cloud.html.erb (0.0ms)
>     Rendered plugins/redmine_contacts/app/views/notes/_last_notes.html.erb (10.0ms)
>     Rendered plugins/redmine_contacts/app/views/common/_contact_data.html.erb (0.0ms)
>     Rendered plugins/redmine_contacts/app/views/common/_recently_viewed.html.erb (1.0ms)
>     Rendered plugins/redmine_contacts/app/views/contacts/index.html.erb within layouts/base (27.0ms)
>   Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 121ms (ActiveRecord: 54.5ms)
>   ActionView::Template::Error (wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)):
>       86: <% end %>
>       87: 
>       88: <% if Redmine::VERSION.to_s >= '3.3.3' %>
>       89:   <%= context_menu %>
>       90: <% else %>
>       91:   <%= context_menu url_for( {:controller => "contacts", :action => "context_menu"} ) %>
>       92: <% end %>
>     app/helpers/application_helper.rb:1157:in 'context_menu'  plugins/redmine_contacts/app/views/contacts/index.html.erb:89:in'_plugins_redmine_contacts_app_views_contacts_index_html_erb___275016466_86436972'
>     lib/redmine/sudo_mode.rb:63:in `sudo_mode'